# Cisco Prime NCS not starting

Tags: cisco, monitoring, nms

I have received the Cisco Prime OVA file and which we placed onto an Oracle virtual environment. We turn the VM on and the CLI boots, When we try to start the NCS service we get errors.

```
HOSTNAME/USER# ncs start

Starting Network Control System...

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.cisco.wnbu.udi.impl.UDIManager.isPhysicalAppliance(UDIManager.java:184)
        at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.start(WCSAdmin.java:335)
        at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.runMain(WCSAdmin.java:281)
        at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.main(WCSAdmin.java:901)
```

Logs

```
HOSTNAME/USER# show logging   
    07/18/13 10:25:38.878 INFO  [system] [main] Setting management interface address to 192.168.0.10
    07/18/13 10:25:38.884 INFO  [system] [main] Setting peer server interface address to 192.168.0.10
    07/18/13 10:25:38.884 INFO  [system] [main] Setting client interface address to 192.168.0.10
    07/18/13 10:25:38.884 INFO  [system] [main] Setting local host name to HOSTNAME
    07/18/13 10:25:40.341 ERROR [system] [main] THROW
    java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:419)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
            at com.cisco.server.persistence.util.OracleSchemaUtil.openConnection(OracleSchemaUtil.java:277)
            at com.cisco.server.persistence.util.OracleSchemaUtil.dbServerUp(OracleSchemaUtil.java:836)
            at com.cisco.packaging.DBAdmin.dbServerUp(DBAdmin.java:1429)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.status(WCSAdmin.java:833)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.status(WCSAdmin.java:757)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.wcsServerUp(WCSAdmin.java:637)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.start(WCSAdmin.java:294)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.runMain(WCSAdmin.java:281)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.main(WCSAdmin.java:901)
    Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
            at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:375)
            at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:422)
            at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:678)
            at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:238)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1054)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:308)
            ... 15 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
            at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:209)
            at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:123)
            at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:353)
            ... 20 more
    07/18/13 10:25:40.347 INFO  [admin] [main]
    07/18/13 10:25:40.347 INFO  [admin] [main] Starting Network Control System...
    07/18/13 10:25:40.347 INFO  [admin] [main]
    07/18/13 10:25:40.394 ERROR [admin] [main] Problem using CARS API:
    com.cisco.cars.fnd.CARSException: CARS_FAILURE : -999 : Failed to get UDI configuration. : Failure occurred during request
            at com.cisco.cars.fnd.CARSException.analyzeReturnCode(CARSException.java:118)
            at com.cisco.cars.serviceEngine.impl.EngineAdminServiceImpl.getUDI(EngineAdminServiceImpl.java:66)
            at com.cisco.wnbu.udi.impl.UDIManager.generateUDI(UDIManager.java:69)
            at com.cisco.wnbu.udi.impl.UDIManager.setPersistenceDirectory(UDIManager.java:139)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.start(WCSAdmin.java:332)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.runMain(WCSAdmin.java:281)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.main(WCSAdmin.java:901)
    07/18/13 10:25:40.396 ERROR [admin] [main] Problem using CARS API:
    com.cisco.cars.fnd.CARSException: CARS_FAILURE : -999 : Failed to get UDI configuration. : Failure occurred during request
            at com.cisco.cars.fnd.CARSException.analyzeReturnCode(CARSException.java:118)
            at com.cisco.cars.serviceEngine.impl.EngineAdminServiceImpl.getUDI(EngineAdminServiceImpl.java:66)
            at com.cisco.wnbu.udi.impl.UDIManager.generateUDI(UDIManager.java:69)
            at com.cisco.wnbu.udi.impl.UDIManager.setVirtualPID(UDIManager.java:169)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.start(WCSAdmin.java:333)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.runMain(WCSAdmin.java:281)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.main(WCSAdmin.java:901)
    07/18/13 10:25:40.397 ERROR [admin] [main] Problem using CARS API:
    com.cisco.cars.fnd.CARSException: CARS_FAILURE : -999 : Failed to get UDI configuration. : Failure occurred during request
            at com.cisco.cars.fnd.CARSException.analyzeReturnCode(CARSException.java:118)
            at com.cisco.cars.serviceEngine.impl.EngineAdminServiceImpl.getUDI(EngineAdminServiceImpl.java:66)
            at com.cisco.wnbu.udi.impl.UDIManager.generateUDI(UDIManager.java:69)
            at com.cisco.wnbu.udi.impl.UDIManager.setPhysicalPID(UDIManager.java:154)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.start(WCSAdmin.java:334)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.runMain(WCSAdmin.java:281)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.main(WCSAdmin.java:901)
    07/18/13 10:25:40.397 ERROR [admin] [main] Problem using CARS API:
    com.cisco.cars.fnd.CARSException: CARS_FAILURE : -999 : Failed to get UDI configuration. : Failure occurred during request
            at com.cisco.cars.fnd.CARSException.analyzeReturnCode(CARSException.java:118)
            at com.cisco.cars.serviceEngine.impl.EngineAdminServiceImpl.getUDI(EngineAdminServiceImpl.java:66)
            at com.cisco.wnbu.udi.impl.UDIManager.generateUDI(UDIManager.java:69)
            at com.cisco.wnbu.udi.impl.UDIManager.getUDI(UDIManager.java:112)
            at com.cisco.wnbu.udi.impl.UDIManager.isPhysicalAppliance(UDIManager.java:184)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.start(WCSAdmin.java:335)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.runMain(WCSAdmin.java:281)
            at com.cisco.packaging.WCSAdmin.main(WCSAdmin.java:901)
```

Any Help is appreciated

Comment: While Cisco Prime NCS is only supported for VMWare ESX, the first thing you are supposed to do is run **setup** in the CLI.  Also, what release are you trying to run?

Comment: `Cisco Application Deployment Engine OS Release: 2.0
ADE-OS Build Version: 2.0.1.038
ADE-OS System Architecture: x86_64

Copyright (c) 2005-2010 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
All rights reserved.
Hostname: HOSTNAME


Version information of installed applications
---------------------------------------------

Cisco Prime Network Control System
------------------------------------------
Version : 1.1.1.24
`

Comment: Here is the [Quick Start Guide](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/net_mgmt/prime/network_control_system/1.1/quickstart/guide/ncs_qsg.html) if you haven't seen it yet.  Have you run setup yet?

Comment: This is an adhoc project i picked up with little to no knowledge of where the project originally stood. I believe they set up has been configured/ran as the running config has some content within it.

Comment: @bigbash - good call, I assumed that 'setup' had already been run.

Comment: @smoothbSE I figured that maybe setup wasn't run since in the log I saw connection was refused.  Thought maybe the database wasn't configured or started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prime/NCS is only supported on Vmware ESX 4.x and 5.X.
see 
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/wireless/ncs/1.1/release/notes/NCS_RN1.1.html#wp167866

and 
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/netmgtsw/ps6504/ps6528/ps12239/data_sheet_c78-715144.html
for more details.

Comment: Hello smoothbSE thank you for responding! Virtualization is not one of my strongpoints, but why would the OVA file released by cisco even boot on an Oracle VM and have basic network/cli functionality? Is there any tweaks or known cases where prime/NCS works on oracle VM software?

Comment: I can't say for sure why it partially works, perhaps it has something to do with the way the Hypervisor presents the NICs or some other emulated hardware spec the application checks for. In any case, it's not officially supported on that platform, so you won't get any help from Cisco TAC.